# How Do I Use Selenium To Click On The Third Div Class "link' If They All Share The Same Div Class?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, click

I am using selenium with python. All of the HTML shares the same div class "links". There are seven links in total on the page, each with the same class and part of the same name. I was wondering how to click on the web element if they have the exact same name <div class"link">

Selenium with python using chrome webdriver.

```
<div class="aux">
  <div class="links">
     <a class="view" href="/pmc/articles/PMC1403861/">Summary</a>
     <a class="view" href="/pmc/articles/PMC1403861/?report=classic&amp;page=1">Page Browse</a>
     <a class="view" href="/pmc/articles/PMC1403861/pdf/jeabehav00206-0003.pdf">PDF–1.6M</a>
     <a class="view citationexporter" href="#" data-citationid="PMC1403861" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">Citation</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the css selector like bellow:

```
.find_element_by_css_selector('div.links a[href*="pdf"]').click()
```

Or if you want to use a sequence:

```
.find_element_by_css_selector('div.links a:nth-child(3)').click()
```

Reference:

[CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

[CSS :nth-child() Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Try using below syntax -

Python:

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class = 'links']/a[3]")).click();
```

Java:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'links']/a[3]")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath with indexing of element.

e.g:

**//div[@class='links']/a[3]**

or

**//div[@class='links']//following::a[3]**

For more details refer below URL:

https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html

Answer (score 1):

To find the 3rd class with class name links.

```
elem=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='links']")[3]

elem=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.links:nth-child(3)")
```